# What does this line of code do?

Tags: c, bit, bit-shift

Confused as to what this  code does

```
for (L=0; L < levels; L++, N_half>>=1){
    func( y, N_half);
} // end: levels for loop
```

In particular this  " N_half>>=1 "

Thanks

Comment: How is this related to bits and bit-shifting?

Comment: Because that's the behavior of the operator OP is asking about.

Answer (score 9):

It advances the loop by dividing N_half by two at every iteration. It is equivalent to:

```
for (L=0; L<levels; ++L, N_half=N_half / 2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`N_half>>=1` performs a 1-place bitwise shift-right on N_half, which (for non-negative numbers) divides it by 2.

`>>=` is to `>>` as `+=` is to `+`.

Answer (score 1):

>>= operator shifts number's digits k positions at right

examples:

binary form

```
N = 101010111 // 2-base  arithmetic system
N >>= 1; // `division` by 2
N: 010101011
```

decimal form

```
N = 123456 // 10-base  arithmetic system
N >>= 2; // `division` by 10^2
N: 001234
```

as *usual*,  the numbers in memory are in binary form and >>=1 is equivalent to division by 2.

Comment: ???  How is ">>= 2" division by 100?  Your example with decimal representation makes no sense to me.  Please clarify?

Comment: It's the shift operation in the decimal form. Not binary. You cannot apply it with the `standard` >>= unless you have a Class for decimal numbers. Ex. 345 >> 1 is 345/10, 345 >> 2 is (345/10)/10.

Comment: Ah: an overloaded operator.  I've never encountered that type of overloading for >>.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If N_half is a positive or unsigned integer, it halves it.

Comment: RaphaelSP - there is no standard that indicates that twos complement notation must be used. It's only guaranteed to work for unsigned and positive numbers, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

It right shifts N_half by 1 (i.e. divides it by two) and stores the result back in N_half

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same as

```
for (L=0; L < levels; L++)
{
  func(y, N_Half); 
  N_Half /= 2;
}
```

The question has been rephrased since I answered it, such that this is no longer valid, but added for completeness: If nothing else is done within the loop, it is equivalent to:

```
N_Half >>= levels;
```

Caveats:

- if N_Half < 2^levels (0 for several iterations)
- if N_Half < 0 (first rightshift will depending on the implementation make it a positive number)

Comment: You need to look at the original code again - it did not call 'floor', and the function it called took y as an extra argument.

Comment: Also, the behaviour of right-shift on negative (hence, necessarily, signed) values is not guaranteed to convert the value to positive.  The C standard explicitly leaves it up to the implementation and the shift can copy the sign bit or insert zeroes; both are correct (though a given compiler may only use one or the other technique).